# How to map 2 dimensional data from dexie table for e.g. graphical vizualization?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter, dexie

I'm developing an angular app and have used dexie for the indexdb used inmy app.
This is working very well but now I want to extract some data and vizualize them by e.g ngx-charts.

```
this._items = await this.indexdbService.items.toArray();
```

The items are complex personl data and I want to extract e.g. just an array of touples with according name/value pairs like

```
"date": x
"weight": y
```

which I could then display graphically.

Of course, I could do that manually by parsing all of the items by hand
but I would wonder if that is not better done by Dexie board means, but unfortunaltely I can't find anything in the docu.
I just find filter functionality but what I'm looking for is rather a mapping funtionality which returns the array of the touples.

Any hints are very much appreciated, thanks a lot.

Bye and best regards

All what I did so far is reading the documentation about a mapping functionality but until now I did not find any result.